# How to display the shortest name in a group?

Tags: sql, mysql

My table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `character_unique` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
        `category` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
        `name_without_stop_words` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
        `name_first_word_with_exception` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
        `master` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
        `nb_letter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `character_unique_count_index` 
(`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to group the data by the columns `name_first_word_with_exception` and `category`. In the grouped records, I want to display the `name_without_stop_words` column with the shortest string length in the group.

In general, it works fine, except for situations like this. The category "Harry Potter" with "name_first_word_with_exception" = "Patronus" contains the following values for "name_without_stop_words":

```
Patronus d'Harry Potter - Translucide
Patronus Ron Weasley - Translucide
Patronus Hermione Granger - Translucide
Patronus Remus Lupin
Patronus Albus Dumbledore
Patronus Severus
Patronus Minerva McGonagall
Patronus Remus Lupin
Patronus Severus Snape
```

But when grouping, the shortest name turns out to be "Patronus Albus Dumbledore," although the actual shortest name here is "Patronus Severus"

I tried using a subquery, in this case, everything works correctly, but verrrry slowly!

```sql
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT name_without_stop_words 
     FROM character_unique 
     WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%', 'Harry Potter', '%') 
        AND name_first_word_with_exception = character_name 
     ORDER BY nb_letter LIMIT 1) as name_without_stop_words 
FROM (
    SELECT id as unque_character_id,
       null as id_character_added_manually,
       category,
       name_first_word_with_exception as character_name,
       master,
       count
    FROM character_unique 
    WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%', 'Harry Potter', '%')
    GROUP BY character_name, category
) as t1;
```

Here is how the correct version of the grouped records looks like:

[image]

How can I find the shortest string in a group?

Comment: I wonder why `name_without_stop_words` is defined as a larger value than `name`. I would expect removing text would mean it could be shorter, if anything.

Comment: Also: what version of MySQL? Because the answer is very different if you're still stuck on a 5.7 release.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn 5.7

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn name_without_stop_words is the initial version after parsing, and name_first_word_with_exception (aka character_name) is the result of applying certain filters to name_without_stop_words.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to group the data by the columns name_first_word_with_exception and category. In the grouped records, I want to display the name_without_stop_words column with the shortest string length in the group.

Assuming you're not stuck in a 5.7 release, the solution here is a windowing function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select id as unque_character_id,
       null as id_character_added_manually,
       category,
       name_first_word_with_exception as character_name,
       master,
       count,
       row_number() over (partition by character_name, category 
                          order by length(name_without_stop_words) ) rn
    from character_unique 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: The version is exactly 5.7

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Oof, that's rough. I know 5.7 itself is a littler newer (2015), but unfortunately it's still rooted in the 2004-era platform. MySQL  basically stagnated near the end of the Sun era and beginning of the Oracle. It didn't advance for over a decade while the industry changed around it. 5.7 and earlier don't really qualify as modern databases anymore. Lack of window functions is one of MANY reasons why. You REALLY want to get to 8.0 release if you can.

Comment: This is not my decision. On my servers, the latest versions of MariaDB are installed. In this case, the client's server has MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel it happens. Just make sure the customer is aware that as of last month (October 2023) version 5.7 is **fully deprecated** and no longer even gets security patches. If it were me, I'd give them this fix but then also tell them you are not willing to touch unsecured software, so they'll need to upgrade before you can help them again.

Answer (score 1):

I find solution:

```sql
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';

SELECT id                             AS unque_character_id,
       NULL                           AS id_character_added_manually,
       category,
       name_first_word_with_exception,
       name_without_stop_words        AS character_name,
       master,
       count
FROM (
    select character_unique.name_first_word_with_exception, character_unique.category, name_without_stop_words, master, count, id
    from character_unique
    join (
        SELECT cu.name_first_word_with_exception, category, MIN(LENGTH(name_without_stop_words)) as min_lngt
        FROM character_unique AS cu
        WHERE cu.category LIKE CONCAT('%', 'Harry Potter', '%')
        GROUP BY name_first_word_with_exception, category
    ) as join_query on character_unique.name_first_word_with_exception = join_query.name_first_word_with_exception
    where character_unique.category like concat('%', 'Harry Potter', '%')
        and length(character_unique.name_without_stop_words) = join_query.min_lngt
    group by name_first_word_with_exception, category
) AS t1;
```

Comment: See how much easier this is to follow when spend a few more moments on formatting? Also, this is a personal preference, but when there are multiple layers of nesting like this I like to deliberately alternate the use of keyword capitalization between layers. It helps to understand what clause belongs with what part of the query.